# Javascript: Passing large objects or strings between function considered a bad practice

Tags: javascript

Is it considered a bad practice to pass around a large string or object (lets say from an ajax response) between functions? Would it be beneficial in any way save the response in a variable and keep reusing that variable?

So in the code it would be something like this:

```
var response;

$.post(url, function(resp){
   response = resp;
})

function doSomething() {
  // do something with the response here
}
```

vs

```
$.post(url, function(resp){
   doSomething(resp);
})

function doSomething(resp) {
  // do something with the resp here
}
```

Assume `resp` is a large object or string and it can be passed around between multiple functions.

Comment: Passing function parameters is preferable to cluttering the global namespace.

Comment: @Malcoda it doesn't have to be global, it could be in a closure.

Comment: Why do you think passing arguments to a function would be bad?

Comment: Passing object references in JavaScript is not expensive at all.

Comment: I think @Pointy is right in that passing large objects around is not expensive. Even if you assume your response object is not global (ie you've wrapped it in another function) you may want to think about the cost of the closure. Depending on where your "doSomething" function goes, "response" may never go out of scope.

Comment: And I guess it also depends on what you want to achieve with those functions. Lets just say you passe a big array containing multiple objects from one request to another, you might want to consider splitting the request by object and sending multiple request rather then one big request. But it all depends on your design pattern, your coding style, who is gonna maintain the code and how it is going to be maintain, your système capabalities and all, etc.

Comment: in functional programming you pass everything, and it's good.

Comment: Assigning outward as in `response = resp;` is bound to make code hard to maintain (if it works at all, given the inevitable race condition). Assigning out of a closure might seem useful, but I've always found a better solution, and the better solution usually involves firing off a callback, passing direct arguments, and looking at the callback's return value. If that strategy seems too ordinary, well it earned its ordinariness by being effective and maintainable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Objects and strings in javascript are passed by reference. (Technically by value of reference, which means reassigning with `=` the variable inside the function won't affect the variable outside the function, but that's besides the point for this question.)

That means that it is not expensive to pass them to functions because no copy is made.  All that is passed to the function is just a pointer to the original object and this is efficient.

---

You need to also realize that your first scheme does not even work properly:

```
var response;

$.post(url, function(resp){
   response = resp;
})

function doSomething() {
  // do something with the response here
}
```

because of the timing of things, you don't know when to call `doSomething()`.  `$.post()` as you show it is asynchronous and thus you have no idea when it is actually done.  The `resp` value in your code MUST be used from the completion function.  You must either use it in the completion function or call something from the completion function and pass `resp` to it (like your second example).  Only then will you get the timing correct for when that data is available.

Comment: @djechlin - you're making a technicality here out of the language.  As I say, they are passed as a pointer to the original object and no copy of the object is made.

Comment: you may as well make your answer technically correct instead of just "you get the idea" correct.

Comment: @djechlin - Please explain what "by value of reference" means in terms that anyone reading here would understand and how it's different than "by reference".  I know what's going on inside the language, but I would like to see if one can explain that term in an easy to understand way that doesn't make it harder to understand what is going on here.

Comment: @djechlin - hmmm, the jury's out for me on whether your addition makes the answer easier to understand or just adds a description of a somewhat irrelevant technicality.

Comment: A lot of users get the idea that Javascript is pass by reference somehow, then come crying back to SO when it doesn't work as expected, so it's particularly bad when otherwise good answers are sloppy about this. If my parenthetical confuses the user probably should spend some time being confused by this. Yes, this is my opinion and I see how it's debatable, but I do stand by it.

Comment: In Wikipedia's terms, JS is a mixture of pass-by-value and "pass-by-sharing". But pass-by-reference is certainly incorrect. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_sharing#Call_by_sharing . How a primitives are passed is actually an implementation detail. It could be that the value is indeed copied, but I'd argue that engines are optimizing that case since primitives are immutable anyway.

Comment: @FelixKling - "pass by sharing" is an interesting phrase to try to represent the in-between (pass by ptr, but not full back-reference) though used on it's own without an explanation, it wouldn't be meaningful to most people because it isn't a well understood standard term.  If I had to pick a single phrase, I'd probably use "passed internally as a pointer to the original object" such that the object isn't copied when passed and so properties of the original object can be changed.

Comment: @jfriend00: I agree. It's still pass-by-value IMO, just that the value is a reference. From the outside this must be utterly confusing :)

Comment: @mr-smee - here's a good read on value vs. reference and argument passing: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_02.htm